# How do I run my query and add the convert_tz(FROM (FROM_UNIXTIME

Tags: mysql, unix, timestamp, convert-tz

This will be simple for you. I have a query that returns all the information in the table but the dates are all Unix timestamp and I need to convert that one column.

These are my 2 strings and I just need to know how to link them together:

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM `wrd_project_payment_transactions`
```

The conversion:

```
SELECT  CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datemade`), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')  
FROM  `wrd_project_payment_transactions`
```

I'm a noob so be gentle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datemade`), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00') AS convertedTime  
FROM  `wrd_project_payment_transactions`
```

Comment: Ok. Awesome. Works perfectly. Thanks so much!